# Placeholder styles for multiple vendors not working

Tags: css, placeholder

I stumbled upon very weird bug. I defined a `::-webkit-input-placeholder` rule which coloured the placeholder. Then I added the `::-moz-placeholder` to it, combining them into one rule:

```
#textinput::-webkit-input-placeholder, #textinput::-moz-placeholder  {
    color: red;
}
```

Meanwhile each of these selector works on it's own (webkit only or moz only), together separated by comma they don't work at all.
See the examples in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petrchutny/jSTaZ/3/), which you can try in both webkit and firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that when a browser encounters an invalid selector it ignores the whole list of selectors. `-moz` is not recognized by webkit and `-webkit` is not recognized by firefox. That's why it fails in both browsers

BTW, according to [this comment from CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/#li-comment-96772), looks like IE7 behaves differently